# Cannot update packages on ubuntu 11.10, please help

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Cannot update on ubuntu 11.10 getting error as " http://packages.ros.org oneiric Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116 "

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42433/cannot-update-packages-on-ubuntu-11.10,-please-help/) by [Vegeta](https://answers.ros.org/users/2476/vegeta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 340 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you add the ros package repository key correctly as shown on the [installation page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu)? Did you execute the following command?

```
wget http://packages.ros.org/ros.key -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4